# Currying template with parameter from another template

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, currying

I have class `Foo`, which has two template parameters, `A` and `B`:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct Foo {};
```

Also I have class `Base`, which has one template template parameter:

```
template<template<typename B> typename Foo>
struct Base {};
```

I want to write class `Derived` assuming the following:

- `Derived` has one template parameter (`A`)
- `Derived` extends class `Base`
- `Derived` passes as template parameter to class `Base` class `Foo`, but with one parameter "currying" (`A`)

How can I do this?

---

Here is my ([not working](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/iWGht4)) solution:

```
template<template<typename B> typename Foo>
struct Base {};

template<typename A, typename B>
struct Foo {};

template<template<typename A, typename B> typename Foo, typename A>
struct BindFirst {
    template<typename B>
    using Result = Foo<A, B>;
};

template<typename A>
struct Derived : Base<

        // error is here
        typename BindFirst<Foo, A>::Result

> {};
```

Which gives me error:

> template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template

Comment: `BindFirst<Foo, A>::template Result` (no `typename`, it's a template).

Comment: Live demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/RpsRbT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template `Base` expects a template as the first parameter but you attempt to pass a dependent type (indicated by `typename`), hence the error message.  Moreover, the nested alias `Result` inside `BindFirst` is a template and therefore would require a template parameter for use with `typename`.  So instead of

```
typename BindFirst<Foo, A>::Result
```

you have to tell the compiler that `Result` is in fact a template, using

```
BindFirst<Foo, A>::template Result
```

[Live example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/NFz6gR)